# Annotated recursive data types with different type of annotation in AST

Tags: haskell, compiler-construction, abstract-syntax-tree, generic-programming

In a toy compiler I am writing I want to use generic recursive data types to represent abstract syntax trees (ASTs), possibly annotated with some attribute.

The parser builds ASTs for expressions, annotated with locations in the source code.

The semantic analyzer takes an AST annotated with locations, and results in a monad that, when run, returns a corresponding AST annotated with type information.

The purpose of the semantic analyzer is to type check the expression, reporting any errors found in the process. The calculated type of the expression should be used as an annotation in the original tree, so that at the end every tree node will be annotated with its type.

With the semantic analyzer fully implemented, a RWS monad will be used, as it will need an environment for compiling let expressions and variables, a log of found errors will be generated, and some new constructions in the expression language will need state to be compiled.

I am having issues with the Haskell type system when trying to write the semantic analyzer. The following code demonstrates the kind of issues I am having:

```
{-# OPTIONS_GHC -Wall #-}
{-# LANGUAGE StandaloneDeriving #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts #-}
{-# LANGUAGE UndecidableInstances #-}
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveFunctor #-}
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveFoldable #-}
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveTraversable #-}

module Lang0 where

import Prelude hiding (foldr1,mapM,exp)
import Data.Foldable (Foldable)
import Data.Traversable (Traversable)
import Control.Monad.RWS (runRWS)

newtype Fix f = In { out :: f (Fix f) }

deriving instance Show (f (Fix f)) => Show (Fix f)


data Ann x f a = Ann { attr  :: x    -- ^ the annotation
                     , unAnn :: f a  -- ^ the original functor
                     }
                 deriving (Eq,Ord,Show,Functor,Foldable,Traversable)

data Range = Range Int Int

instance Show Range where
  show (Range a b) = show a ++ "-" ++ show b

type Name = String

data BinOp
  = Add | Sub | Mul | Div
  | Eq | Ne | Gt | Ge | Lt | Le
  | Con | Dis
  deriving (Eq,Show)

data ExpF r
  = Log Bool
  | Num Double
  | Var Name
  | Neg r
  | Bin BinOp r r
  | Let Name r r
  deriving (Eq,Show,Functor,Foldable,Traversable)

data Type = NUMERIC | LOGIC deriving (Eq,Show)

newtype Exp = Exp { runExp :: Fix ExpF } deriving (Show)
newtype ExpPos = ExpPos { runExpPos :: Fix (Ann Range ExpF) } deriving (Show)
newtype ExpType = ExpType { runExpType :: Fix (Ann ExpType ExpF) } deriving (Show)

type Env = [(Name, Type)]
type Log = [(Range, String)]

semantExp :: Monad m => Fix (Ann Range ExpF) -> m (Fix (Ann Type ExpF))
semantExp (In (Ann pos exp)) =
  case exp of
    Num _ -> return (In (Ann NUMERIC exp))
    _     -> error "unimplemented"

e1 :: ExpPos
e1 = ExpPos (In (Ann (Range 1 2) (Num 8)))

main :: IO ()
main = print (runRWS (semantExp (runExpPos e1)) [] ())
```

When this code is given to the ghc compiler, I get the following:

```
$ ghc --make Lang0
[1 of 1] Compiling Lang0            ( Lang0.hs, Lang0.o )

Lang0.hs:60:38:
    Couldn't match type `Range' with `Type'
    Expected type: ExpF (Fix (Ann Type ExpF))
      Actual type: ExpF (Fix (Ann Range ExpF))
    In the second argument of `Ann', namely `exp'
    In the first argument of `In', namely `(Ann NUMERIC exp)'
    In the first argument of `return', namely `(In (Ann NUMERIC exp))'
```

Why the compiler wants the annotation in the argument and in the result ASTs be of the same type?

Any clues on how to fix this issue?

**Additional observation**: Without the type annotation for `semantExp`, the compiler infers the following type for it:

```
semantExp
  :: Monad m => Fix (Ann Type ExpF) -> m (Fix (Ann Type ExpF))
```

Why the inferred type has the same type for the annotation, both in the argument in the result monad?

Comment: You have the signature `semantExp :: Monad m => Fix (Ann Range ExpF) -> m (Fix (Ann Range ExpF))` so a return value of `return (In (Ann NUMERIC exp))` is a type mismatch.  Did you want `semantExp :: Monad m => Fix (Ann Range ExpF) -> m (Fix (Ann Type ExpF))`?  I can't tell what you're trying to do.

Comment: @TomEllis, that was a mistake of mine when I typed the code. It has been fixed in the question now. Instead of `Range`, it should be `Type` inside the monad. The error reported by ghc still needs clarafication.

Comment: @TomEllis, I have tried to make clearer what I am trying to do in the question.

Answer (score 4):

So you've got this big old term annotated with ranges everywhere. You destruct it, which gives you a range annotation named `pos` and a subterm (still annotated with ranges all over the place) named `exp`. You throw out `pos` and replace it with a type annotation, which is laudable, but then have the audacity to claim that `exp` is annotated with types. But that's clearly not true -- you would have to traverse the entire subterm and rip out all the old annotations for it to be!

The error says this, too, but its language is dry and boring.

Comment: I do not know how I have not seen that! I was trying to share the unannotated tree between the input and output annotated trees, which does not have compatible types. The unannotated tree has to be reconstructed. Rewriting the first alternative of the case expression as follows fixes the issue: `Num n -> return (In (Ann NUMERIC (Num n)))`